# How to get EditorCookie or DataObject for a given JTextComponent in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I am listening on changes in EditorRegistry where I can get which JTextComponent is currently selected. Anyone knows how can I get an EditorCookie or a DataObject for it?

```
JTextComponent jTextComponent = EditorRegistry.focusedComponent();
Document document = jTextComponent.getDocument();
```

And how can I get to which project does it belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataObject is easy one:

```
JTextComponent jTextComponent = EditorRegistry.focusedComponent();
Document document = jTextComponent.getDocument();
DataObject dobj = NbEditorUtilities.getDataObject(document);
```

Than the EditorCookie is easily obtainable through getCookie() method of the data object.

The Project object can be retrieved for the data object by following:

```
Project owner = FileOwnerQuery.getOwner(dobj.getPrimaryFile());
```